# How to compare two columns of excel and bring a text based on values

Tags: excel-2010

I need to compare two columns containing different values and print a text based on values.

Example given below

Cash    Card    A or B
251 3100000 A
(if cash is greater than 250 and Card is greater than 30 lac print "A" else Print "B")

Answer (score 0):

You have basically described the answer:

```
=IF(AND(A2>250,B2>3000000),"A","B")
```

where the only part that is not almost plain English is the location of [AND](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/and.php), which like `OR` and some other functions comes before the components it connects:  *=AND(this,that)* rather than the natural language *this AND that*.